# How to write start dates of each month specific times in excel?

Tags: excel

I thought over and over but couldn't find a solution to this problem:

How would you write each start date of months in 2013 3 times in a column in excel as below:

```
01-01-13
01-01-13
01-01-13
01-02-13
01-02-13
01-02-13
01-03-13
01-03-13
01-03-13
.
.
01-12-13
01-12-13
01-12-13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **A1** enter:

```
=DATE(2013,ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0),1)
```

and copy down.

**EDIT#1:**

to start with an arbitrary cell, use:

```
=DATE(2013,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0),1)
```

and copy down

Comment: What if I have to write the formula in cell Y210?

Comment: Perfect, how did you find this solution? Had you dealt with a similar problem before or have you just found the solution for me? I mean, how do you know which function to use for this problem?

Comment: @alwbtc  The core of the solution is **=ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/3,0)** .   This is a "well-known" way to generate repeating sequences of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first cell to be filled in is in row 2, the formula is:

```
=DATE(2013, INT((ROW()+1)/3), 1)
```

the interesting part, computing month number, is just getting the integer part of division of row number by 3, and the row number needs to be adjusted to get `3` in the first used row (i.e. +1 if you start in second row, +2 if you start in 1st row, -11 if you start in 14th row)